# Hyperlink tel: on click does nothing in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

As the title says when I click on link(tel:) in google chrome on desktop nothing happens, but the mozzila desktop asks me for program to use and on mobile it works fine, the only problem is desktop google chrome version. Can somebody say what is the problem

Comment: I tried it in my browser and it doesn't work in Chrome either, neither does ' callto: '

Comment: I didnt find the solution yet. Did you?